# Elisp - invalid-function error when printing to *Messages*

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am an Elisp newbie tweaking my `.emacs` file to choose the c-mode style based on the file being edited. While doing so I am trying to print to `*Messages*` but it fails.

The exact error is `File mode specification error: (invalid-function (message "This results in an incorrect-function error"))`

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (message "Foo") ;; <- This gets printed                                                                                                                                                              
            (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
              ;; Enable kernel mode for the appropriate files                                                                                                                                                    
           ((message "This results in an incorrect-function error") ;; <- this fails
                 (if (and filename
                        (string-match (expand-file-name "~/src/linux-trees")
                                      filename))

                  ((message "Identified as Linux style") ;; <- this fails                                                                                                                                        
                   (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
                   (c-set-style "linux-tabs-only")
                   (setq ethan-wspace-errors (remove 'tabs ethan-wspace-errors)))
                ;; Otherwise use Google's coding style                                                                                                                                                           
                 ((message "Identified as Google style") ;; <- this fails                                                                                                                                    
                  google-set-c-style
                  google-make-newline-indent))))))
```

Comment: Looks like the first things in the sexp `((message "This results ...") ...` is the sexp containing message, and the first thing in a sexp is always a function. So the error is that is no function `(message "This results ...")`

Comment: @MrBones So, how can I print to `*Messages*` in the body of a `let` or `if` expressions?

Comment: I think `progn` is what you want - see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/progn.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some misplaced parentheses and, as @MrBones's comment indicates, you need to wrap multiple statements in a `progn` when inside an `if` clause:

```
(defun fnx ()
  (message "Foo")
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (message "No longer an incorrect-function error") ; get rid of first "("
    (if (and filename (string-match filename
                                    (expand-file-name "~/src/linux-trees")))
        (progn                                  ; wrap multiple statements in a progn
          (message "Identified as Linux style") ; get rid of first '('
          (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
          (c-set-style "linux-tabs-only")
          (setq ethan-wspace-errors (remove 'tabs ethan-wspace-errors)))
      (progn                                    ; not strictly necessary in else clause
        (message "Identified as Google style")  ; get rid of first '('
        (google-set-c-style)                    ; don't forget parens
        (google-make-newline-indent)))))        ; don't forget parens
```

(Note: I've never used `google-...` before, so I presume you've got the correct functions in there.)

Lastly, it's generally preferred practice to use named functions as hooks rather than lambdas:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'fnx)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine several function calls into one, you need to use a construct like `progn`.

In other words, you can't write:

```
((message "hi")
 (a-function-call))
```

Instead, you have to write:

```
(progn
 (message "hi")
 (a-function-call))
```